# Looking for more intuitive jQuery selectors for grabbing values out of particular input fields in "this" row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table made up of the following rows:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Link</a>
  </td>
  <td>It takes about 3 seconds for a search instead of the normal .3 seconds.
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="priority" size="3" value="-5"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    Functionality
  </td>
  <td>
    8/1/2012 6:57:03 AM</td><td>FarQuad
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="assign">
      <option value="No One" selected="selected">No One</option>
      <option value="Landon" >Landon</option>
      <option value="Steve" >Steve</option>
      <option value="Brandon" >Brandon</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <select class="status">
      <option value="Unassigned" selected="selected">Unassigned</option>
      <option value="Assigned" >Assigned</option>
      <option value="In Progress" >In Progress</option>
      <option value="Completed" >Completed</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="notes" value="Super notes"/>
  </td>
  <td> 
    <input type="button" id="16" Value="Save" onclick="updateThisIssueRow(this)" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the last cell contains a button that will perform an update to the database via ajax.

Here's the beginning of that method:

```
        function updateThisIssueRow(thisRowsButton) {

            var issueIDInput, newPriorityInput, newAssignPersonInput, newIssueStatusInput, newIssueNotesInput;

            var $currentRow = $(thisRowsButton).parent().parent();

            issueIDInput = thisRowsButton.id;
            newPriorityInput = $currentRow.children().eq(2).children().first().val();

            alert("Value of newPriorityInput is: " + newPriorityInput);
.
.
.
```

Now, I basically need to grab the values of issueIDInput, newPriorityInput, etc. with jQuery and then feed them to the rest of the ajax function, which works. I'm looking for more reader-friendly jQuery selectors for these values. I know I can grab everything like I did for newPriorityInput (which works), but my boss doesn't know much of jQuery (and therefore dislikes/distrusts it). Are there more intuitive selectors for these?

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

How about,

```
    function updateThisIssueRow(thisRowsButton) {
        var issueIDInput, newPriorityInput, newAssignPersonInput, newIssueStatusInput, newIssueNotesInput;
        var $currentRow = $(thisRowsButton).closest('tr');
        issueIDInput = thisRowsButton.id;
        newPriorityInput = $currentRow.find('.priority').val();
        alert("Value of newPriorityInput is: " + newPriorityInput);
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Oh that is awesome! The find() thing is exactly what I needed! (closest is cool too) (have to wait 7 minutes it says...)